# Keyboard shortcut to close MS Paint without saving

Tags: microsoft-paint

What is a keyboard shortcut  in `MS Paint 11` to close without saving? Yes, I know about `Alt+F4`, but that brings up the annoying prompt to save the file, forcing me to click a button with my mouse. I rarely want to save my Paint canvas - I just want to quickly close without saving. I have to do this many times per day and would love a quick keyboard shortcut to do it.

In older MS Paint, for example on Windows 7, I could dismiss the "do you want to save" prompt by pressing the `N` key. But they removed that functionality in Win11, and as far as I can tell, they force you to mouse-click the `Don't save` button to close without saving.

I can hit `TAB` twice and then `ENTER`, but that is 3 extra key presses instead of 1.

There must be a quicker keystroke(s) to close Paint 11 without saving. Thanks in advance for any advice.

[image]

Comment: they removed that functionality in Win11, and as far as I can tell,  ...   Yes.  Windows 11 is vastly different from Windows 7.  Maybe put Run the taskkill command to kill the process. . in a batch file and run that.

Comment: So windows 11 completely breaks accessibility...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and wrote an AHK script for this:

```
; CTRL+Q (while MS Paint has focus) to execute

#SingleInstance Force
^q::
Send !{f4}
Send {TAB}
Send {TAB}
Send {ENTER}
```

Works great.

Comment: For those who don't know what AHK is, and don't care to search, it's AutoHotKey.